# How to access Google Trends without JavaScript?

Tags: google-trends

I noticed that Google Trends [drastically changed](http://insidesearch.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/insights-into-what-world-is-searching.html) it's UI and now fails to work without JavaScript enabled.

Where to access the plain old good Web 1.0-ish Google Trends?

Alternatively, how to configure NoScript to allow the necessary set of additional scripts, but only at Google Trends page, nowhere else?